# Python passing variable dates to function

Tags: python, function

Hello: making progress but still struggling. I have the following json:

```
json =
{
  "emeter": {
    "get_daystat": {
      "day_list": [
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 1, "energy": 0.651000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 2, "energy": 0.349000 },
        { "year": 2016, "month": 10, "day": 3, "energy": 0.481000 }
      ],
      "err_code": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I am using a linear search to find the energy value from a specific day with this function:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(json)

def get_energy_value_by_date(obj, year, month, day):   
    for value in obj['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']:
        if value['year'] == year and value['month'] == month and value['day'] == day:
            return value['energy']


energy = get_energy_value_by_date(parsed_json, 2016, 10, 2)
```

So far so good. What I need to do next is find the energy value for various days. For example today (assume json is valid):

```
import datetime
day_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")
month_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m")
year_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")

parsed_json = json.loads(json)

def get_energy_value_by_date(obj, year, month, day):   
    for value in obj['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']:
        if value['year'] == year and value['month'] == month and value['day'] == day:
            return value['energy']


energy_today = get_energy_value_by_date(parsed_json, year_now, month_now, day_now)
print energy_today
```

When I run this script it returns

```
None
```

I must be missing something basic here. What I need is the ability to pull the energy value for any day of any month of any year for further processing.

Thanks!

Baobab

Comment: print day_now, month_now etc. Debug from there.

Comment: The problem is you need to cast your variables to ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple issue with your script: [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), according to the docs, will

> return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string.

The keyword here being "string." See the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> day_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")
>>> day_now
'04'
```

This does not equal the integer value of the day in your JSON file:

```
>>> '04' == 4
False
```

Therefore, the equality check will always fail and `None` will be returned. One way is to use `int` to convert this value to an integer. A better way is to use the attributes of a `datetime` object to get the integer values:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().year
2016
>>> datetime.datetime.now().month
10
>>> datetime.datetime.now().day
4
```

I would also advise passing just a `date` object to the function and unpacking it there: it prevents redundancy and cleans up the function signature. You should also use `date.today()` instead of `datetime.now()` (since time is irrelevant) and then make the comparison in one operation. The full function could be something like this:

```
def get_energy_value_by_date(obj, current_day):   
    for value in obj['emeter']['get_daystat']['day_list']:
        if current_day == datetime.date(value['year'], value['month'], value['day']):
            return value['energy']

current_day = datetime.date.today()
energy_today = get_energy_value_by_date(parsed_json, current_day)
print (energy_today)
```

Comment: @Baobab I edited my last function to include some simper logic--take a look at that as well!